# Is it possible to index non-latex PDF inserted using \includepdf?

Tags: pdfpages

I have a collection of PDFs in which some are Latex generated and some are external PDFs that were created using other software. I want to combine these PDFs to create a master PDF.

```
\documentclass[titlepage]{article}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\author{A}
\title{T}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\includepdf[pages=-19, \addtotoc={1,-,1,Name,lab}]{A.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=-, \addtotoc={1,-,1,Name,lab}]{B.pdf}

\end{document}
```

I have tried to use `\addtotoc` with `\includepdf` but it requires a Latex recognized section for me to add an index entry. My question is, is it possible to insert index entries to non-latex documents inserted using `\includepdf`?

Also, is it possible to reference pages inside the inserted document?

Comment: Are you asking for hyperlinks? Or you want a variant of `\index` that marks an entry at, say, the third page of `B.pdf`? Can you add some **non-working example** to show us the user interface in your mind?